# OpenSSL s_client and Python SSL module disagree on the certificate for a hostname

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having an odd problem. It looks like OpenSSL's "s_client" tool doesn't like my AppEngine application's SSL certificate to the point of not even acknowledging it ("no peer certificate is available"), but Python's SSL module reports the issuer, date range, serial number, subjects, etc.., as if there was no problem at all.

I'd assume that there is some subtle misconfiguration with my SSL certificate, but, as AppEngine provides a very simple wizard for uploading certificates, saying that there is a misconfiguration is to say that Google's functionality is broken... Which I doubt is the case.

I'd love some insight into this if someone else has experienced it.

s_client:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.abc.com:443
```

s_client output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3073997000:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 225 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Python 3.3 test script:

```
import socket

from ssl import wrap_socket, CERT_NONE, PROTOCOL_SSLv23
from ssl import SSLContext  # Modern SSL?
from ssl import HAS_SNI  # Has SNI?

from pprint import pprint

# Stole this from "requests" package.
def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, cert_reqs=None,
                    ca_certs=None, server_hostname=None,
                    ssl_version=None):

    context = SSLContext(ssl_version)
    context.verify_mode = cert_reqs

    if ca_certs:
        try:
            context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
        # Py32 raises IOError
        # Py33 raises FileNotFoundError
        except Exception as e:  # Reraise as SSLError
            raise SSLError(e)

    if certfile:
        # FIXME: This block needs a test.
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)

    if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
        return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

    return context.wrap_socket(sock)

hostname = 'www.abc.com'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((hostname, 443))

sslSocket = ssl_wrap_socket(s,
                            ssl_version=2, 
                            cert_reqs=2, 
                            ca_certs='/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/requests/cacert.pem', 
                            server_hostname=hostname)

pprint(sslSocket.getpeercert())
s.close()
```

Test script output:

```
{'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
            (('organizationName', 'GeoTrust, Inc.'),),
            (('commonName', 'RapidSSL CA'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Oct  2 20:01:20 2014 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Sep 29 02:17:38 2013 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '0E45AF',
 'subject': ((('serialNumber', 'd3tVuFeMunyn/gFFucMFHgZ2iBihdthR'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', 'GT22884059'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName',
               'See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName',
               'Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)'),),
             (('commonName', 'www.abc.com'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.abc.com'),
                    ('DNS', 'abc.com')),
 'version': 3}
```

Comment: Possibly an SNI issue (your Python client may be using it, depending on what's supported), try `s_client` with the `-servername` option. It could also be an SSL/TLS version issue, try `s_client` with `-ssl3`, `-tls1`, `-no_ssl3`, `-no_tls1`, ...

Comment: My AppEngine is configured for SNI, yes. It's a good suggestion, but it doesn't seem to tell me anything. Though -ssl1, -ssl2 are listed in the help, it says that they're invalid options. Passing -tls1, -tls1_1, and -tls1_2 don't make a difference. I'd be willing to accept that AppEngine expects an SSL version that I can't provide, in theory, except that I doubt I could only support versions that Google doesn't.

Comment: The difference is more likely to be between `-ssl3` and `tls1`. `openssl s_client -connect www.abc.com:443 -servername www.abc.com -tls1` should make a difference.

Comment: Actually.. I was actually missing the "servername" parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not including the "servername" parameter in my "s_client" call.